# Running migrate.exe from powershell for Cloud Services Project?

Tags: entity-framework, powershell, entity-framework-migrations, azure-cloud-services

I'm trying to write a powershell script that runs migrations for a cloud service project:

```
$migrator = "C:\Path\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\migrate.exe" 
$migrateCommand = "$migrator file.dll /StartUpDirectory=C:\path\bin\Test /connectionStringName:myconnection /startUpConfigurationFile:C:\path\app.config /verbose"  
Invoke-Expression $migrateCommand
```

And I keep getting the following error when I run the script: "Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

I have copied migrate.exe to my bin folder where all the dll's are and I'm using absolute path's for the startupdirectory and configuration file. Can't seem to figure out what I'm missing? Also another question I had was could migrate.exe be only used with webrole/workerrole projects?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is migrator was searching entityframework.dll in the same working directory. You could change the working directory to the folder which contains your entityframework.dll